# Escape Utf-8 inside of json array using php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I created a `php` script which execute `select` statement on postgres database. I transform the result into json string and pass it to `javascript` variable using `<? echo $a; ?>` line.
Problem I can't solve is that my `json` from `php` contain polish characters (`utf-8`) encoded, and when `javascript` get this value i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` and it is totally fine because the string is not escaped.
Here it is how i do this:
`php` generation of json:

```
<? $result_json = json_encode($result); ?>
```

and how I pass it into js:

```
options_json='<? echo $result_json; ?>';
```

When I debug in the browser my `options_json` look like:

```
options_json='[{"code":"za\u0105e ba\u0144stre.".....
```

I tried `escape()` `utf8_encode()` and `addslashes()`. First with no result, the `addslashes()` function removed the error but it destroyed `json` structure so I could not pares it back..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try to return json encoded values like this example :

```
$arr_rslt=array();
$query=" Select col1,col2,col3 from tbl";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
{

    $arr_rslt[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($arr_rslt);
```

on client side if you using $.ajax or $.post then manipulate this in their callbacks.
also use this in your $.ajax.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful for you i am using the below function to encode the arrays those having arabic texts.Just try the below function. I am not dealing with slashes.

```
      public function utf8_encode_all($dat) // -- It returns $dat encoded to UTF8
      {
          if (is_string($dat)) return utf8_encode($dat);
          if (!is_array($dat)) return $dat;
          $ret = array();
          foreach($dat as $i=>$d) $ret[$i] = $this->utf8_encode_all($d);
          return $ret;
       }
```